# dual authentication schemes in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, identity

In Visual Studio 2013 you can specify the authentication scheme. Two options are "individual user accounts" and "organizational accounts". The setting is a radio button so I cannot choose both. But in my application I need to support both. Is this possible to do manually by merging the configurations from projects created using the wizard. Or is there an underlying logical separation, in which case I would have to have two separate web sites for these two authentication schemes?

Comment: The short answer is that it's possible, but a huge pain in the butt when using integrated pipeline mode (which most people would want to use).  The longer answer is, save yourself some headaches figure out a different solution.  See http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/

Comment: So is the best/easy solution to just have two separate web sites?